# Azure website, Cname redirect, SEO

Tags: azure, seo

So i have the following scenario:

I have a domain: mydomain.ro. I am hosting the domain on a host provider in Romania. I will add a Cname record and A record in my DNS settings of my host provider that will point to an azure hosted website. Will this affect my seo? Is it still considered that i have the website hosted in my country so that i don't mess up the seo for google.ro?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  The trick here is the method of redirection.

Generally speaking, there are 2 main methods of redirection.

1. a 301 redirect ("permanently moved"), or,
2. a 302 redirect ("temporarily moved").

You'll want to ensure that you use a 301 redirect ("permanently moved") in order to not anger Bing, Google, etc.

This works differently with various DNS providers, but most provide you with the choice between 301 and 302.  If yours doesn't, you'll want to find one that does.

There's some good information here on the whole 301/302/SEO impact thing. http://www.theinternetdigest.net/archive/301-redirects-seo.html

Good luck,

-adam

My Windows Azure Blog - http://www.stratospher.es

My Twitter-er-er: http://twitter.com/stratospher_es

Comment: From what i read the last hours (and understand) search engines like google doesnt necesary take the location of your host into consideration but actually the speed and uptime record. This is a very interesting fact